# What is the effect of using common colloquial words in page title?

Tags: seo, title

I am wondering what is the effect of using common words while writing a title of webpage.

For Example for my [home page](http://mrnepal.com), I am trying to write an effective title. I worked out on few titles like:

- Starx (Nabin Nepal): Wanna know about me?
- Starx (Nabin Nepal): Software Developer & Designer
- Nabin Nepal, You can call me Starx

And now I am wondering if using colloquial words like `wanna` and common terms like `you can call me` is considered good for a title.

Could someone clear this concern?

Answer (score 3):

Most common words are treated as [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) by Google, so words such as `You` `Can` and `want` are to some degree ignored.

This is because many words give the same meaning, for example:

EG1. `Do you want a Freelance Website Designer?`

EG2. `Do you need a Freelance Website Designer?`

EG3. `Looking for a Freelance Website Designer?`

EG4. `After a Freelance Website Designer?`

As you can see all of the above have the same meaning and it would be pointless to treat all differently if the page is about the same. You can find a list of stop words at [link-assistant](http://www.link-assistant.com/seo-stop-words.html).

**Keywords near the front... but not always**

A good title is one that describes your page in a short sentence, cater for humans and not bots. It is normally better to try and include keywords at the start of the title rather than the end but sometimes this is not possible and you should ***ALWAYS PUT YOUR VISITORS FIRST***.

So if we was too look at your title examples:

```
Starx (Nabin Nepal): Wanna know about me?
Starx (Nabin Nepal): Software Developer & Designer
Nabin Nepal, You can call me Starx
```

These are pretty short and only number 2 includes keywords, so lets say you want to put primrary focus on the phrase Starx and Nabin Nepal but want to include that you are a developer then a title such as this would work well:

```
About Starx (Nabin Nepal) - Software Developer and Designer for 10 years
```

If you want to put more weight on the keywords developer then you can include it in a sentence at the start of the title rather than the end, such as:

```
Read about Software Developer and Designer Starx (Nabin Nepal)
```

If you want 'Max weight on keywords Starx Nabin and Nepal without dilution then something like this would work well:

```
Nabin Nepal, You can call me Starx
I'm Nabin Nepal, but just call me Starx
Nabin Nepal, Just call me Starx
Read more about Nabin Nepal AKA Starx
```

Just remember as long as people understand what your pages are about before they click, then your titles are good ;)